# Issues with passing all values entered on a form, via formData, with fetch API

Tags: javascript, forms, express, fetch-api, form-data

Why formData goes empty to my express+mongodb server? I've some problems with querySelector and addEventListener, but for now thats ok. However, I don't find a way for sending all values of my form to the server. Please, someone help me?

```
document.querySelector('#enviar- 
cadastro').addEventListener('click', Cadastrar);


Cadastrar('http://localhost:5000/usuario/novo')
 .then(response => console.log(response.json()))
 .then(data => console.log(data))
 .catch(error => console.log(error));

 function Cadastrar(url) {
   const formDados = new FormData(document.querySelector('#signup'))

   return fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(formDados),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
   })

 };
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for what to do when you get an answer to a question here.

Answer (score 1):

First of all console.log(formDados) inside Cadastrar and see what you get. 
This should also help: https://code.lengstorf.com/get-form-values-as-json/

Comment: Man, that's working! The code shared by you saved my project! Thank you very much

Comment: Give me arrow up ('This answer is useful") please so I can help others better.